# Either one of Two required fields in contact form 7 validation while submit in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I tried [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-two-required-fields-but-only-one-must-be-filled?replies=7#post-1972435) but not getting proper result How to do this with contact form 7

```
$("input.last4digit").on('change',function(){
   $("input.receipt").removeClass('wpcf7-validates-as-required');
   $("input.receipt").attr({'aria-required':'false', 'aria-invalid':'false'});
}); 

$("input.receipt").on('change',function(){
   $("input.last4digit").removeClass('wpcf7-validates-as-required');
   $("input.last4digit").attr({'aria-required':'false', 'aria-invalid':'false'});
});
```

I used jQuery to remove class and attributes on change of one field It works on change but after submit button pressed Attributes changes again. and not getting proper result. Any suggestions please....

Comment: you can use jQuery condition in header of theme after giving and id/class to the two fields.

Comment: the link in your question doesnt work

Comment: Sorry for the mistake I edit it. Now it is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.wpcf7-form').submit(function(){

        var last_4_digit = $('input.last4digit').val();
        var receipt_no = $('input.receipt').val();

        if ( last_4_digit == ''  && receipt_no == '' )
        {
            $('input.last4digit').addClass('not-valid');
            $('.not-valid-tip').text("This or Below field is Required");
            $('.not-valid').focus();
            return false;
        }
        else if( last_4_digit != ''  || receipt_no != '' )
        {
            $('.not-valid-tip').text("");
        }
        else
        {}
    });
```

After doing this jQuery I got the result as my requirement Its just simple but if you want to go with contact form 7 functionality I am still finding solution for that.